# MS Access Alter Statement: change column data type to DATETIME

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime

I have a column named as `recordTime` in my Access DB table `table1`.

This column is of `TEXT` type right now, and most of its value are in format as: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss`, but there are also some wrong records like this: `yyyy-mm- ::`.

Now I would like to change the data type of this column from `TEXT` to `DATETIME`. I tried with the following query but nothing happens:

```
             ALTER TABLE table1
             ALTER COLUMN recordTime DATETIME;
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What's the error. I would add new column with datetime. Then update that column using format command.

Comment: Hi, @Hiten004, there isn't any error, the query just doesn't do. I don't think I can add new column that have same values I have in `recordTime`, right?

Comment: Did you check the design of your table? I tried it with some sample dates and it's working; well except for the badly formatted dates which got turned into `NULL`.

Comment: Hi, @Jerry, the design of the table was okay. But the data inserted later was sometimes wrong as I mentioned above, did you try with wrong records like this: `yyyy-mm- ::`?

Comment: @Lyon That's what I was telling you. Those records turned into `NULL` for me. You might want to create another column to manipulate those records before running the `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @Jerry, that's what also I asked after Hiten004 commented. I actually have no idea how to manipulate those records by creating a new column. any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what date are you expecting to get from `yyyy-mm- ::`? Say, what should `2013-09- ::` become?

Comment: Hi, @Jerry, I would prefer just deleting them since they are wrong records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running these:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD NewDate DATE
```

Then run

```
UPDATE table1
SET NewDate = RecordTime
WHERE RIGHT(RecordTime,4) <> '- ::'
```

You can then delete the `RecordTime` and rename `NewDate`.

I prefer adding a new column just in case there are any issues with the `UPDATE` and you can compare the 'cleaned' column and the initial data before proceeding.

Comment: I am sorry, even the first query doesn't execute. And I don't know why.

Comment: @Lyon Oops, I put the wrong table name, I usually deal with GL's and it's really fast for me to type those instead of `table1` ^^; Fixed.

Comment: you are kidding, right? Sure I changed table name to my own before I execute that query. But thanks anyway. I've tried, Both SELECT and UPDATE statement work well, but ALTER statement, no.

Comment: @Lyon I don't know why it's not working on your Access... It's working fine in mine. Are you running the two queries separately? But if it doesn't work, you can manually create the new column in Design View. Just make sure the data type is date when you create it.